# Linq Error : Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm

I am running Linq query in `CRM2013` and throwing error :

> Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

My Code is as below

```
var conntionRecord1Id = (from connectionBase in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("connection")
                         where connectionBase["record1roleid"] != null
                         select connectionBase["record1id"]
                        ).Distinct();

var query = from opportunity in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
            where conntionRecord1Id.Contains(opportunity["opportunityid"])
            orderby opportunity["createdon"] ascending
            select new
            {
                Topic = opportunity.Attributes.Contains("name") == true ? opportunity["name"] : null,
                OpportunityId = opportunity.Attributes.Contains("opportunityid") == true ? opportunity["opportunityid"] : null,
                PostalCode = opportunity.Attributes.Contains("new_address_postalcode") == true ? opportunity["new_address_postalcode"] : null,
            };
```

erro is throwin in second query.

Comment: You don't join to conntionRecord1Id so your second query makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side of the where clause has to be an attribute name and the right hand side must be a value.

This is the problem line in the query:

```c#
// lhs must be something from the entity
where conntionRecord1Id.Contains(opportunity["opportunityid"])
```

Andy Meyers has a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720786/1817350

A QueryExpression with ConditionOperator.In might be more suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21093122/1817350

Comment: Hi @bvrce,var qe = new QueryExpression("opportunity"); qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "opportunityid", "new_address_postalcode"); qe.Criteria.AddCondition("opportunityid", ConditionOperator.NotIn, conntionRecord1Id.Cast<Object>().ToArray()); qe.Distinct = true; var results = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(qe); but this is throwing me error : The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:query.

Comment: Try calling .ToList() on conntionRecord1Id before the case: conntionRecord1Id.ToList().Cast<Object>().ToArray()