# c# linq crm select where contains

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, contains

I'm trying to select from CRM entity with "`contains`" key.

I tryed this:

```
var results = crm.new_supplycontractSet
    .Where(x => x.new_city != null && 
        x.new_city.Name.Contains("myChars")) 
    .ToList();
```

but it give me this error:

> Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

and this:

```
var result = (
    from c in crm.new_supplycontractSet
    from a in crm.new_comuneSet 
    where a.new_name.Contains(comune)
    where c.new_city.Id == a.Id
    select c)
    .ToList();
```

But i can't figure out how to do it. The second try gives me this error:

> A 'SelectMany' operation must be preceeded by a 'Where' operation that filters by an entity ID.

How can I select by a contains filter?  "`x.new_city`" is an entity ref from crm.new_comuneSet.

PS:
I've just read something about the inaccessibility of the "`entity.entityRef.Name.Contains()`" because the "Name" property is not ground level and so it's not available for the "`.contains`" check.

Comment: The code you posted is missing a `)` is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry, my bad coping, I fix it! Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `new_supplycontractSet` in your entity?

Comment: Let start from the beginning. What is the problem with your first try?

Comment: Your second code has a stray `;` after the first `where`.

Comment: Sorry all, I was with the phone and I missclicked some keys, question updated now!

Comment: CRM LINQ do not allow using `Contains` inside a `Where` clause, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720786/3002584) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end i got it. instead of `contains` clause, I had to install `SqlClient` and use the following:

```
  results = (from x in crm.new_supplycontractSet
                           where x.new_city != null
                           where x.new_address != null
                           where SqlMethods.Like(x.new_city.Name, "city")
                           where SqlMethods.Like(x.new_address.Name, "street")
                           select ....).ToList();
```

hope this will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try converting your field and your filter to lower or upper case.

```
  var results = crm.new_supplycontractSet
    .Where(x => x.new_city != null && 
        x.new_city.Name.ToLower().Contains(("myChars").ToLower())) 
    .ToList();
```

I think is better if you use StartsWith instead (and if is possible).

Comment: Hi, I tried it but I still have the same problem "invalid whre clause".. I updated my question but still stuck on it :(